# Coercivity of a bilinear form and the associated differential equation

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, banach-spaces, bilinear-form, coercive

I have to prove that the following bilinear form is not coercive in $H_0^1(0,1)$.
$$a(u,v)=\int_0^1x^2u'(x)v'(x)dx$$

Is it as simple as saying since there is no lower bound given on $x^2$ that is positive so we cannot prove that it is coercive?

Also I am trying to find the associated differential equation. For that I tried to test with two different equations and to come up with given the bilinear form. Those are

$$-u''-x^2u=f$$
and
$$-xu''=f$$
both with Neumann boundary conditions equal to zero. But cannot seem to get to the bilinear form.